# is there a wordpress function to detect if a plugin is not up-to-date?

Tags: php, wordpress, auto-update

I'm trying to add an auto-update setting to my wordpress plugin. I found how to update is, but running the update consistently when no update is available will crash the website. is there a wordpress function that can check if my plugin has an update available? or a global variable? or any way to get most recent version number from wordpress plugins? I need a way to detect if the plugin is already up-to-date. thanks.

this function I found online [here](https://wpreset.com/programmatically-automatically-download-install-activate-wordpress-plugins/) does Not seem to work

```
function is_plugin_updated($plugin_slug){
  if (!function_exists('get_plugins')) {
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
  }
  $all_plugins = get_plugins();

  if(!empty($all_plugins[$plugin_slug])){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

and this function just gives me the current version of the plugin, not the most recently released version

```
function get_plugin_version(){
  $plugin_data = get_file_data(__FILE__, array('Version' => 'Version'), false);
  $plugin_version = $plugin_data['Version'];
  return $plugin_version;
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
function upgrade_plugin($plugin_slug){
  include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
  wp_cache_flush();

  $upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader();
  $upgraded = $upgrader->upgrade($plugin_slug);

  return $upgraded;
}
```

I'm needing something more like this

```
function upgrade_plugin($plugin_slug){
  if(!pluginUpToDate()){
    include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
    wp_cache_flush();

    $upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader();
    $upgraded = $upgrader->upgrade($plugin_slug);

    return $upgraded;
  }
}

function pluginUpToDate(){
  //detect if plugin version is current and up to date
}
```

Comment: Wordpress automatically looks for updates if your plugin is hosted on wordpress.org if its not hosted on wordpress's plugin website you cannot use the automatic updated and will have to write your own

Comment: the plugin is hosted on wordpress.org, but I'm trying to add an auto update feature. Do you know of any way I can retrieve results from wordpress automatic update check?

Comment: Wordpress detects if there is an update if you want the plugin to update automatically once there is an update you will need to create a hook on checking for the update and if the value is true then call the update method